# How to open a link when I read a .rst text file?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

If we type :help in vim, read the vim help file, and see a blue (or say green-blue) word, that word is a link. We can put the cursor in the word, and press Ctrl-] on the keyboard, then we go to the linked contents.

I am new to .rst files. My question is, when I read a .rst file, and see a blue (or say green-blue) word, can I press any key so I can go to the linked contents?

Comment: The reason these "links" work in the help files is because vim have created tags files for you. Find a proper program to generate tags file rst and you will be able to jump to these as well. See `:help 29.1` for more information.

Comment: @AndreasLouv Thanks! Oh, I see. I installed Exuberant Ctags 5.9, and ran `#ctags -R *`, but 'tag' file is not created. Could you kindly advise, please?

Comment: @AndreasLouv Thank you very much! 'tags' file created. The tags work! When I Ctrl+] on a function call, it jumps to the function definition. :)

Comment: I created the comment as an answer, so that you can accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason these "links" work in the help files is because vim have created tags files for you.

Find a proper program to generate tags file rst and you will be able to jump to these as well.

See `:help 29.1` for more information.

Comment: Download Exuberant Ctags. Run
``#cd ~/proj``    
``#ctags -R .``    
When you Ctrl-] on a function call, you will be taken to the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

reStructuredText has [lots of kinds of hyperlinks](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#hyperlink-targets), that Vim may or may not be able to follow natively or with a little help.

Implementing all that sounds like a fun Saturday afternoon project but, if you are in a hurry, you might want to take a look at [gu-fan/riv.vim](https://github.com/gu-fan/riv.vim/blob/master/doc/riv_instruction.rst#links) which provides hyperlink navigation, among *many* other things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am new to `.rst`. Sorry after I read both the linked resources you provided, I still do not know how to open a link when I read a `.rst` file in `vim`. Could you kindly further advise, please?

Comment: If not `vim`, then what app should I use to open `.rst` files, so I can open the links in it?

Comment: There is no further advice to make. The second link points to a Vim plugin that, as I said, does what you want so the next step is for *you* to install it and learn how to use it by reading its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to external links like HTTP: and things like that, just type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> in normal mode. See also this link: https://sbulav.github.io/vim/neovim-opening-urls/

Comment: Yes, gx works for external links. Thanks!